# My program is not sorting as I want it to

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I this program and it is supposed to sort a list of movies in order from greatest to least by looking at its year of publish. here are the methods and I also have a method to print it. It is ordering it in abc order instead of 5,4,3,2,1 order.

```
System.out.println("Sorted by Year - descending:"); 
        sortYears(myMovies,0,myMovies.length-1);
        printMovies(myMovies);

public static void sortYears(Movie4[] myMovies , int low, int high)
    {
        if( low >= high )
            return;

        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        sortYears(myMovies, low, mid);
        sortYears(myMovies, mid+1, high);
        mergYears(myMovies, low, mid, high);
    }

    public static void mergYears(Movie4[] myMovie, int low, int mid, int high)
    {
        int tempLow = low;
        int tempMid = mid;
        int indexCnt =0;

        while( tempLow < mid || tempMid < high)
        {
            if( tempLow > mid)
            {
                myMovie[indexCnt].equals(myMovie[tempMid]);
                tempMid++;
            }
            else if( tempMid > high)
            {
                myMovie[indexCnt].equals(myMovie[tempLow]);
                tempLow++;
            }
            else if(myMovie[tempLow].getYear() < myMovie[tempMid].getYear())
            {
                myMovie[indexCnt].equals(myMovie[tempLow]);
                tempLow++;
            }
            else
            {
                myMovie[indexCnt].equals(myMovie[tempMid]);
                tempMid++;
            }
            indexCnt++;
        }

        for(int x = low; x < high; x++)
        {
            myMovie[x].equals(myMovie[x-low]);
        }

    }
```

Movie 4:

```
public class Movie4 {

    // instance variables 
    String title ;
    int year;
    String studio;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class InventoryItem
     */
    public Movie4(String t,int y,String s)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        title = t;
        year = y;
        studio = s;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public String getStudio() 
    {
        return studio;
    }
     @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return title + ", " + year + ", "+studio;
    }
    public boolean equals (Movie4 other)
    {
        return(title.equals(other.getTitle()));
    }
      public int compareTo(Object other) 
        {
        int result;
        String otherTitle = ((Movie4)(other)).getTitle();
        result = title.compareTo(otherTitle);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something missing here: the code for `Movie4`. Hint: there is `Arrays.sort()` too.

Comment: @fge I may be wrong, but I am getting the vibe that the OP wants to implement his/her own sorting system based on the careful consideration to use merge sort.

Comment: Should i post the Movie4 code here?

Comment: All of your `movie.equals(..)` calls are completely useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you compare two `Movie4` objects ?  I suggest 2 ways:

**Option #1:**

Your `Movie4` class must have the `equals()` method overridden. That way your sorting logic would work correctly. See [this](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html).

**Option #2:**

If you want to use the Arrays.sort() method for using in-build sorting, you class must implement `Comparable` and have a `compareTo()` method. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Comment: Uh? No. As this is a comparison here, what is needed is `Comparable` or a `Comparator`.

Comment: @fge Comparable will work with Arrays.sort(). I believe that OP wants to have his/her sorting logic and not use in-build sorting implementations. See my edit above.